# Custom Product Collection Filter

Tags: magento-1.9, filter, product-collection

I created a custom form that search for specific product attribute my form look like this
[image]

```
$location = $this->getRequest()->getParam('location');
$specialization = $this->getRequest()->getParam('specialization');
$name = $this->getRequest()->getParam('name');
$attrSetName = "Group Deal";
$attributeSetId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
    ->load($attrSetName, 'attribute_set_name')
    ->getAttributeSetId();
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_productCollection->clear()
    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', $attributeSetId)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'virtual'));
    //Default Count//
    $count = $_productCollection->getSize();

<?php  if(!empty($location)): ?>
    <?php $_productCollection->clear()->addAttributeToFilter('contact_city', array('like' =>$location.'%' )); ?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php  if($specialization>0): ?>
    <?php $_productCollection->clear()->addAttributeToFilter('doctor_specialization',$specialization);?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php  if(!empty($name)): ?>
    <?php $_productCollection->clear()->addAttributeToFilter('name', array('like' =>'%'.$name.'%' )); ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

The above line of code is how i return my results. How ever when i search with 2 search parameters like name and location im not getting accurate results, Is there any way to improve the search query? Any help would be appreciated very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default addAttributeToFilter add AND condition. You need OR condition on collection use like below

```
$collection->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=> 'someattribute','like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute'=> 'otherattribute','like' => 'value'),
        array('attribute'=> 'anotherattribute','like' => 'value'),
    )
);
```

see also in [Magento Wiki](https://magento.com/help/documentation)

Comment: How can i add pagination to the result list? everytime a go to the next page the query for a custom attribute returns a different result

Comment: add pager block and set your collection to pager